# Spark Streaming csv to Data Frame

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a streaming csv data set that comes in this format

```
2,C4653,C5030
2,C5782,C16712
6,C1191,C419
15,C3380,C22841
18,C2436,C5030
```

I am trying to take the Dstream and convert it into a DataFrame where i should get each field as a column. something like this.

```
col1   col2   col3
 2     C4653  C5030
 2     C5782  C16712
```

and so on.

I am using the following code but cannot get it to work. This is the code that I am using.

```
  val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String,    StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
val lines = messages.map(_._2)
val seperator = lines.map(_.split(","))
lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>

// Get the singleton instance of SparkSession
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

// Convert RDD[String] to DataFrame
val wordsDataFrame = rdd.map(_.split(",")).toDF().show();
}
```

I am getting the following as output for the code I am using.

```
+-----------------+
|            value|
+-----------------+
|[2, C4653, C5030]|
+-----------------+
```

However, I am trying to make it into three columns. Please help.

Comment: Please provide a schema with toDF . Something like this val wordsDataFrame = rdd.map(_.split(",")).toDF("col1","col2","col3").show() Is should work then.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this.

```
val wordsDataFrame = rdd.map { record => {
              val recordArr = record.split(",")
              (recordArr(0),recordArr(1),recordArr(2))
            } }.toDF("col1","col2","col3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a schema with toDF . Something like this `val wordsDataFrame = rdd.map(_.split(",")).toDF("col1","col2","col3").show()` should work then